# When is there a path between two minimal prime ideals?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, zariski-topology

Recall a path from a point $x$  to a point $y$ in a topological space $X$ is a continuous function $f$ from the unit interval
$[0,1]$ to $X$ with $f(0) = x$ and $f(1) = y$. Now let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ and $Spec(R)$ be the set of all prime ideals of $R$ with the Zariski topology. It is well-known that if $P$ and $Q$ are two prime ideals of $R$ with $P\subseteq Q$, then there exists a path from $P$ to $Q$. Now let $\frak{p}_1$  and $\frak{p}_2$ be two minimal prime ideals of $R$. I am looking for equivalent conditions under which there exists a path between $\frak{p}_1$  and $\frak{p}_2$.

Comment: Shouldn't this just be equivalent to the existence of a zig-zag of specialisations from one to the other?

Comment: @R. van Dobben de Bruyn: as you stated, if there exists a finite zig-zag of specializations from one to the other we are done. But does the existence of a path imply a finite zig-zag of specializations from one to the other? Also, infinite zig-zag of specializations (especially uncountable) is also a problem.